# Is there a more similar syntax for calling function on elements in array in parallel and serially than map and for?

Tags: javascript

I currently have the following code

```
    if (state.headless) {
      state.conversions.map(convertSingle);
    } else {
      for (const c of state.conversions) {
        await convertSingle(c);
      }
    }
```

I dislike that the semantic difference between the first and second case is only that in the first case I want to run the functions in parallel while in the second case I want to run in parallel, but syntactically they look completely different.

Is there some alternative syntax that makes the first and second case more similar? I do not want to define some helper functions for this that would complicate the code, since I don't have this situation anywhere else in my code.

Comment: Don't forget the `await Promise.all(…)` around the concurrent case?

Comment: In the for loop I wait for each individual promise to resolve because the UI becomes snappier that way, In the headless case with the map I just want everything to run in parallel and don't need to know when it is all done.

Comment: You might not care, but it's still recommended, at least to slap an error handler on it…